# ckeidtor - html values are not being saved in db on live server CI

Tags: codeigniter, ckeditor

I am working in CodeIgniter and I am stucked in an unusual problem. I have some text in ckeditor and everything is working just fine. but when I try to save `list`

```
<ul>
  <li>item one</li>
  <li>item two</li>
</ul>
```

after submitting it says

**FORBIDDEN**

> You don't have permission to access
>   /myproject/folder/controler/method/id on this server.

kindly spread some light why is it happening

Comment: Can you give us some more information to work with. Can we see some relevant snippets of your code?

Comment: it is already false #pradeep

Comment: I am working in CI and using built in `post()` method of CI to post data... #WebCode

Comment: Looks more like an apache configuration issue. Can you use postman to see if you can hit /myproject/folder/controler/method/id or let me know if you still get the 403 error

Comment: what is `postman`

Comment: https://www.getpostman.com/ - Its a free API Development/Test software. If you use that to simulate your POST request it can help you to debug your problem. I use it all the time.